# Playframework Comet socket catch disconnect on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework, playframework-2.0

So I'm implementing an application that requires messages to be sent to the browser in real time. Currently this is working fine. When I receive a message I an Untyped Actor similar to the clock example.

What my issue is though is I would like to be able to reconnect the web page when the comet socket gets disconnected. Currently in chrome with comet sockets the loading icon continuously spins. Is there a way I can catch a disconnect message for the iframe/comet socket? Or is there something that I can poll in javascript/jquery? So i can then just reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reconnect "the web page" (in other words, make your browser send another request to server, with `window.location.reload()` or some other method), standard [play.libs.Comet.onDisconnected](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/libs/Comet.html#onDisconnected%28play.libs.F.Callback0%29) handler is of no use to you - its domain is a server-side, not a client-side.

To make your client-side manage possible blackouts by itself, you may need to implement 'heartbeat' scheme. The client application will ping your server when too much time has been passed since the previous message. One possible way to do this:

```
var CometProcessor = {
  processMessage:         function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  },
  handleHeartbeatTimeout: function() {
    alert('Heartbeat process timeout');
  },
  handleHeartbeatError: function() {
    alert('Heartbeat process error');
  },

  timeoutPeriod:  10000,      // in milliseconds
  timeoutId:      0,          // will contain an ID of the current 'checking' timeout
  checkHandler:   null,       // will contain a link to XHR object

  checkBeat: function() {
    // storing the reference to created XHR object:
    this.checkHandler = $.ajax({
      url:     your_server_url,
      // set it to the URL of ping script, that will respond instantly

      timeout:     1000,
      // this is configurable, but obviously it makes little sense setting this param
      // higher than `timeoutPeriod`

      success:     $.proxy(function() {
        // so this particular heartbeat request check went through ok,
        // but the next may not be so lucky: we need to schedule another check
        this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(
          $.proxy(this.checkBeat, this), this.timeoutPeriod);
      }, this),

      error:       $.proxy(function(x, t) {
        if (t === 'timeout') {
          this.handleHeartbeatTimeout();
        }
        else {
          this.handleHeartbeatError();
        }
      }, this)
    });
  },

  message: function(message) {
    // when we receive a message, link is obviously functioning,
    // so we need to stop all the checking procedures
    if (this.checkHandler) {
      this.checkHandler.abort();
      window.clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
      this.checkHandler = null;
    }
    processMessage(message); // this is where the actual processing takes place

    // when we done with processing, we need to setup the heartbeat again:
    this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(
      $.proxy(this.checkBeat, this), this.timeoutPeriod);
  }
};
```

Leveraging this object at server-side is quite easy: you just have to replace the line similar to the one in [this example](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaComet)...

```
Ok.stream(events &> Comet(callback = "parent.cometMessage"))
```

... with this:

```
Ok.stream(events &> Comet(callback = "parent.CometProcessor.message"))
```